# How to configure 404 error page correctly

Tags: struts2, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I have configured 404 error to some error page. But thats working when I am giving anything wrong URL which consists a DOT (.), but when I am giving some wrong URL which does not have any any DOT(.) its not being redirected to the 404 error page. Instead its throwing NullPointedException.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for this problem and found the answer which worked for me.
The reason for the above problem was the filter class used by me that is FilterDispatcher. Which seems to be deprecated. Instead I used the following one which solved the issue.

```
 <filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>

<filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
</filter-class>
```